# Apply injection to call in methods yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have several services which calls in Controllers. How I can replace next rows:

`$service = new UserService()`
`$service->login();`

to:

`$userService->login();`

I'm using it in few Controllers, maybe need to make changes in config or something.. I didn't found such cases in yii2 docs.

Answer (score 0):

Make parent controller with this code in it:

```
private $userService;

public function __construct($id, $module, UserService $userService, $config = [])
{
    $this->userService= $userService;
    parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
}
```

Extends all controllers with your new controller (BaseController for example).

Then in your action you can use it like:

```
$this->userService->login();
```

If it is not what do you seraching for... please give more information

Comment: Thanks for your response! But maybe there is exists another method like applying "userService" to new parameter in config file and then use it?

Comment: You can set it in container. Check this: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container